# I cant get a Entity object through his foreign key

Tags: spring, spring-security, foreign-keys

I have a project in Spring and MySQL. I have two tables:

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="role_id")
    //role_id e numele cheii straine din baza de date
    private Role role;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = HospitalProfile.class)
    private Set<HospitalProfile> hospitalProfileSet;

}
```

and this one:

```
@Table(name = "hospital_profile")
public class HospitalProfile {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String address;

    private String city;

    private String country;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "profile_picture")
    private byte[] profileImage;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "hospitalProfile", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = DoctorProfile.class)
    private Set<DoctorProfile> doctorProfileSet;
}
```

I want to get a HospitalProfile based on user_id. I got the user because he is the current logged in user. I've tried this code:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String username = authentication.getName();
        System.out.println(username); //hospital@gmail.com


        User userLoggedIn = userRepository.findByEmail(authentication.getName());
        System.out.println(userLoggedIn.getEmail());
        System.out.println(userLoggedIn.getRole());
        System.out.println(userLoggedIn.getId());

        HospitalProfile hospitalProfile = hospitalProfileRepository.findByUserId(userLoggedIn.getId());
```

All the souts print something good, but when i try to findByUserId(is a JpaRepository method) it returns null. I am sure that i have a HospitalProfile linked to the actual user.

....................................................................

Comment: Sure that `findByUserId` is jparepository method? seems that its custom method in hospitalProfileRepository. if so, show it pls

Comment: @GeorgiiLvov Repository
public interface HospitalProfileRepository extends JpaRepository<HospitalProfile, Integer> {
    HospitalProfile findByUserId(int userId);
}

Comment: Okay, you try to return single HospitalProfile, but each user has many hospitalprofiles. You have to fox your findByUserId method

Comment: @GeorgiiLvov and how do you recommend to do this? If my loggedf in user has his PK as FK in HospitalProfile, i dont understand why I cant find a Hospital by his UserId FK.

Comment: Why you need to use hospitoalRepo, and not simple `userLoggedIn .getHospitalProfileSet()` from found user by email?